# Alternative to ORA_HASH?

Tags: oracle, hash, oracle11g, checksum

We are working with a table in a 3rd party database that does not have a primary key but *does* have a unique index.

I have therefore been looking at using the ORA_HASH function to produce a *de facto* unique Id by passing in the values of the columns in the unique index.

Unfortunately, I can already see that we have a few collisions, which means that we can't derive a unique id using this method.

Is there an alternative to ORA_HASH that would provide a unique id for a unique input?

I suppose I *could* generate an Id using DBMS_CRYPTO.Hash but I'd ideally like to get a numeric value.

**Edit**

The added complication is that I then need to store these records in another (SQL Server) database and then compare the records from the original and the replica tables. So `rank` doesn't help me here since records can be added or deleted in the original table.

Comment: Why not just use `rank`?

Comment: @mureinik - I've added an explanatory comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH could be used to generate a high-bit hash (high enough to give you a very low, but not zero, chance of collisions), but it returns 'RAW' not 'NUMBER'.

To guarantee no collisions ever, you need a one-to-one hash function.  As far as I know, Oracle does not provide one.

A practical approach would be to create a new table to map unique keys to a newly generated primary key.  E.g., unique value ("ABC",123, 888) maps to 838491 (where you generated 838491 using a sequence).

You'd have to update the mapping table periodically, to account for inserted rows, and that would be a pain, but it would let you generate your own PKs and keep track of them without a lot of complication.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. That's a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE (
   name      VARCHAR2, 
   base      NUMBER, 
   hash_size NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that caps out at around 24-25 bits.  So, for even small tables (10,000 rows), you're almost guaranteed to have collisions.